# why create_sheet() in python not working?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to create a new worksheet in my existing excel file through a python code. I am using openpyxl module. I used create_sheet method but not working..plz help. my code is show below
`import openpyxl as op
file=op.load_workbook('C:/Users/pavan m sunder/Desktop/hotelpythondata.xlsx')
file.create_sheet('newsheet')`

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's "`import openpyxl as op`" and not just "`openpyxl as op`"

## After creating the sheet, you also need to save the excel.

```
import openpyxl as op
xlfile = 'C:/Users/pavan m sunder/Desktop/hotelpythondata.xlsx'
file=op.load_workbook(xlfile)
file.create_sheet('newsheet')

file.save(xlfile)               # You can save it as the same file or specify another path/ filename
```